# World readable writable __override__ directory in Xamarin application sandbox

Tags: android, xamarin, file-permissions, sandbox

Can anyone shed some light about designation of `__override__` folder Xamarin creates in application sandbox? As it turned out it is world readable writable which is causing problems with security checks. I have tested it for production app on stock device and got following:

```
shell@m0:/data/data/com.myapp/files/.__override__ $ mkdir testdir
shell@m0:/data/data/com.myapp/files/.__override__ $ echo "content" >> testfile
shell@m0:/data/data/com.myapp/files/.__override__ $ ls
testdir
testfile
shell@m0:/data/data/com.myapp/files/.__override__ $
```

Is there any way to get rid of this folder or make it protected as the rest of application sandbox folders?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have asked Xamarin support directly and as it turned out it was a regression bug which will be fixed with further updates: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=37422

Answer (score 0):

That is (was) a known vulnerability in Xamarin.Andriod prior to 5.1.

Rebuild / redeploy your app using **Xamarin.Android 5.1** or newer in ***release mode***.

#### Current Releases:

- Stable:

  - Xamarin.Android 6.0.1
- Alpha Preview 2 – Cycle 6 Service Release 1

  - Xamarin.Android 6.0.1.5

> Xamarin for Android <5.1 DLL Hijack Vulnerability From: ValdikSS  Date: Tue, 19 May 2015 16:49:51 +0300
>
> -----BEGIN PGP SIGNED MESSAGE----- Hash: SHA256
>
> Xamarin for Android prior to version 5.1 allows to replace internal
>   DLL files inside the APK with files on SD card  which are not in a
>   secure storage. Malicious application without any special permissions
>   could drop backdoored DLL files into
>
> /storage/sdcard0/Android/data/app_id/files/.**override**/
>
> and the victim application would use files from SD. Not just the main
>   application library could be hijacked, but also Xamarin's System.dll
>   and Mono.Android.dll, which are  shipped in all Xamarin for Android
>   applications.
>
> Developers should rebuild their applications using Xamarin for Android
>   5.1 or newer in the release mode.
>
> This vulnerability was found by accident, which allowed me to eat for
>   free for a month.
>
> Timeline:
>       03.04.2015 Vulnerability is found
>       07.04.2015 Message sent to Xamarin
>       08.04.2015 Xamarin acknowledged the vulnerability
>       29.04.2015 Fixed stable version released
>
> -----BEGIN PGP SIGNATURE-----

Re: [http://seclists.org](http://seclists.org/fulldisclosure/2015/May/78)

Comment: I've read information about this vulnerability and even the article from a guy who discovered it, but I'm already using proper Xamarin Android in release mode (Xamarin Studio: Version 5.10.1 (build 6); Xamarin.Android: Version: 6.0.0 (Indie Edition)) and my issue is presence (and access right) of this folder in internal memory.